# Which java pattern to implement with similar Data Transfer Objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, dto

I have a class which I currently use like a dto and I've to create another class with similar properties (less than the actual has), it's there a pattern related to this? I thought that an adapter would help but I couldn't realize how.

```
class ONE {
  ObjectA oa;
  ObjectB ob;
  ObjectC oc;
  String id;
  String name;
  String someId;
  String country;
}

class TWO {
  ObjectB ob;
  ObjectC oc;
  String name;
  String someId;
  String country;
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: Do you have a constraint that prevents you from using inheritence (Class ONE extends TWO)?

Comment: I don't, the classes are similar! I thought to use composition over inheritance but I couldn't know if the microservice that´s using the DTO would work without altering its behavior. Using composition wouldn´t I alter its structure?

Comment: That depends on whether the microservice accesses the DTO fields directly or through getters and setters. Getter and setter methods can be modified to accommodate a new internal structure, if that structure is not exposed to clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you must reason whether using inheritance/composition makes sense or not. With the names of class `ONE` and `TWO` it is hard to say, so let me take another example. Say, we have a Vehicle and a Phone class like so,

```
class Vehicle {
    String model;
    String color;
    String type;
}

class Phone{
    String model;
    String color;
    String type;
    String brand;
    Integer core;
    Integer ramInGB;
}
```

Here `Vehicle` and `Phone` class have some fields in common. But you cannot change `Phone` like so

```
class Phone{
    Vehicle v;
    String brand;
    Integer core;
    Integer ramInGB;
}
```

or

```
class Phone extends Vehicle{
    String brand;
    Integer core;
    Integer ramInGB;
}
```

Before using any design pattern anywhere, you must reason whether using it in that scenario is justified. Don't use design patterns just for the sake of using it.

Coming back to the example, if ONE and TWO are not related in any sense you should leave them be. But if they are you can use either inheritance or composition. Here is a [link](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose), you might wanna go through before making that choice.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options to use:

1. [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html): make TWO super class(fewer properties) and ONE sub since it has more properties (properties of TWO and other properties).
2. [Interface and abstract class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html): According to the described problem I suggest to use above inheritance (in 1.).

Example using super and subclass

```
class ONE extends TWO{

    ObjectA oa;

    String id;

}

class TWO {

    ObjectB ob;

    ObjectC oc;

    String name;

    String someId;

    String country;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer composition over inheritance.

```
class ONE {
  ObjectA oa;
  String id;
  TWO ot;
}

class TWO {
  ObjectB ob;
  ObjectC oc;
  String name;
  String someId;
  String country;
}
```